# Could not find client in the context of ApolloConsumer

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

i was working with apollo client but i get error when i access **ApolloClient** instance in child components using **withApollo** HOC

**Error Message:**

Could not find "client" in the context of ApolloConsumer. Wrap the root component in an <ApolloProvider/.>

**Root Component:**
[image]

**Child Component:**
[image]

Comment: Check that `ApolloProvider` and `withApollo` use the same version of context. They might have different instances of context, so it won't see each other. Check versions of packages. Also, from what package do you import `ApolloProvider` from?

Comment: Imported ApolloProvider from @apollo/client

Comment: Its working now